# How to get all HTML links from the DOMDocument?

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I'm trying to fetch all HTML links from a document using the native DOM extension:

```
$items = $xpath->query('//div[@class="cards"]/div[@class="card"]/div/a[@class="card-click-target"]');
```

HTML code is:

```
<div class="cards">
   <div class="card">
      <div><a class="card-click-target" href="http://">Link</a></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

But it gives me an empty object. How to do it correctly?

Comment: It would be much easier to use some sort of libraries like simple html DOM - http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Pedrammarandi, he uses the `DOMXPath` class from the dom extension, which is shipped with the PHP package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to fetch the `a` nodes having `href` attribute, use `//a[@href]` XPath expression, e.g.:

```
$r = $xpath->evaluate('//a[@href]');
foreach ($r as $n) {
  printf("%s: %s\n", $n->textContent, $n->getAttribute('href'));
}
```

*Sample Output*

```
Link: http://domain.com/page
```

If, however, you want the `href` attribute values, use `//a/@href` selector:

```
$r = $xpath->evaluate('//a/@href');
foreach ($r as $n) {
  var_dump($n->value);
}
```

Example fetching all `a` tags with `class` attribute value equal to `card-click-target`:

```
$r = $xpath->evaluate('//a[@class = "card-click-target" and @href]');
foreach ($r as $n) {
  printf("%s: %s\n", $n->textContent, $n->getAttribute('href'));
};
```

Comment: I want to get `href` of element corresponding my HTML dom document and class = `"card-click-target"`

Comment: Look please body question again

Comment: So, and after in loop I can get href as?

Comment: @MisterPi, as in the first example

Comment: Right? `$item->getAttribute("href");`?